# Alternative for fetchAllAssociative()` and execute in doctrine

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I am calling a stored procedure using native sql via doctrine. `fetchAllAssociative()` and `execute` are deprecated. What are the alternatives?

```
    $sql = 'CALL spWithParams(:param)';
    $stmt = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([":param"=>"test"]);
    print_r($stmt->fetchAllAssociative());
```

I am not planning to map the response to entity using `ResultSetMapping()` as mentioned [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/native-sql.html) as I will add my custom wrapper on it.

Comment: What are you expecting back from `spWithParams`? ResultSetMappings can quite happily work with arbitrary data completely seperate from entities.

Comment: @frozenjakalope there is a select statement in it. This code is working fine, it's just I don't want to use the deprecated functions.

Comment: I get that, was just looking for a bit of context around what you're expecting in the results set so I could bash out an example of how you'd do it with an RSM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way of doing this is to use a ResultSetMapping with [scalar results](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/native-sql.html#scalar-results) to select arbitrary fields. You can then execute the query with `getArrayResult()` to achieve the same behaviour as in the provided code.

As an example:

```php
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addScalarResult('my_database_column', 'myField');
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery(
    'CALL spWithParams(:param)',
    $rsm
);
$query->setParameters([":param"=>"test"]);

$results = $query->getArrayResult();
/* 
[
  ['myField' => 'foo'],
  ['myField' => 'bar']
]
*/
```

Comment: This solution won't work if the stored procedure does not return any SELECT statement (for example, the internal logic of the SProc causes that no SELECT is called and it just exists). In that case, SQL will return something like "The active result for the query contains no fields". So either, dont use this, or get your SPs to always TRY to return some active result set, even if knowing it will be empty.